# Typescript not inferring correct type when it changes in a called function

Tags: typescript

When I initialize a variable to null, but with another type as a union (e.g. `number | null`), it seems to lose the non-null type information immediately (the same thing happens with undefined, except if I leave it unitialized, rather than explicitly setting it to undefined).

```
let foo: number | null = null;

foo; //foo's type (seen by mousing over) is "null", not "number | null"

function blah() {
  foo = 123; //foo is "number | null"
}
blah();

foo; //foo's type is "null", not "number | null"
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jBcEB2BXAtgIxAJwgH2RWGAgF5DiBuAWACg7YYb7aoUkBjMASxiQgzAAhgAsAFAEoIAbzoRocMhACMAJgDMzAL51BoycwZxKQA)

Is there a way to access the type of foo correctly there?

Comment: You are printing the value of `foo`, not the type of `foo`.

Comment: And it's always gonna be just one type, regardless of your typescript syntax. Typescript is just a "meta language" which allows you to "think" that you're defining multi-types, but down below (at the Javascript level), this so called "multi-type" decays into one actual type.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't actually referring to the log output (though the second log will output 123, not null). I was looking at foo's inferred type in the ts playground (and vscode) by mousing over it at those spots. If you open the link to the playground, you'll see what I mean. Typescript assumes foo can not be a number in the second call to console.log, even though it is, and was explicitly typed that way.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a known trade off https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998